# How to get total price when incrementing or decrementing quantity?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue in this below code. so basically what I want is each time I press on plus or minus button the total price should increase and decrease. the issue is when I console.log sum variable it works fine in the console but when I add the sum variable in the tag it starts multiplying the total amount by the input number.
[this is when I console logged it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wkyj.png) and [this is when it's on the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49PCl.png)

```js
var increment = document.querySelector('#myform .qtyplus');
var decrement = document.querySelector('#myform .qtyminus');
increment.addEventListener('click', incrementValue);
decrement.addEventListener('click', decrementValue);

function incrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-number').value);
  if (isNaN(value) || value < 1) {
    value = 1;
  }
  value++;
  document.getElementById('input-number').value = value;
  productpagetotal()
}


function decrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-number').value);
  if (isNaN(value) || value < 1) {
    value = 1;
  }
  value--;
  document.getElementById('input-number').value = value;
  productpagetotal()
}


function productpagetotal() {
  var sum = 0;
  var producttotal = parseFloat(document.querySelector('.span').innerText.replace('$', ''));
  var quantity = document.getElementById('input-number').value;
  sum = sum + (producttotal * quantity);
  sum = Math.round(sum * 100) / 100;
  producttotal.innerText = sum;
  console.log(sum)
}
```

```html
<div class="quant">
  <p>Qty</p>
  <form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' id="input-number" name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="last-list">
  <h6 style="font-size: 17px">Free Shipping on Order over $80</h6>
  <h4 class="in-h4">Delivery to pincode 000001 - within 2-4 business days</h4>
  <div class="total-price">
    <span>Total Price</span>
    <span class="span product-total-price">$24.99</span>
    <button class="add-to-card">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But when I add the `sum` variable it starts multiplying the total amount by the input number

Your code has this line inside it, in the `productpagetotal` function:

```
sum = sum + (producttotal * quantity);
```

This is producing the odd behaviour you are experiencing. Changing this line should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your code doesn't have the products total when there is only one hardcoded in.

```
var pt = 29.99
var increment = document.querySelector('#myform .qtyplus');
var decrement = document.querySelector('#myform .qtyminus');
       increment.addEventListener('click', incrementValue);
       decrement.addEventListener('click', decrementValue);

function incrementValue(){ 
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-number').value);
    if (isNaN(value) || value < 1) {
        value = 1;  
    }
    value++;
    document.getElementById('input-number').value = value;
    productpagetotal()
}


function decrementValue(){
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-number').value);
    if (isNaN(value) || value < 1) {
        value = 1;  
    }
    value--;
    document.getElementById('input-number').value = value;
    productpagetotal()
}


function productpagetotal(){
    var producttotal = document.getElementById('product-total');
    
    var quantity = document.getElementById('input-number').value;
     var sum = (pt * quantity);
     sum = Math.round(sum * 100) / 100;
     producttotal.textContent = sum;
     console.log(sum)
}

<div class="quant">
  <p>Qty</p>
  <form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' id="input-number" name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="last-list">
  <h6 style="font-size: 17px">Free Shipping on Order over $80</h6>
  <h4 class="in-h4">Delivery to pincode 000001 - within 2-4 business days</h4>
  <div class="total-price">
    <span>Total Price</span>
    <span class="span product-total-price" id="product-total">$24.99</span>
    <button class="add-to-card">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It actually escapes me how to properly format code. Sorry if this is formatted incorrectly

Comment: Thanx brother it works. I had the total from producttotal variable but wasn't working so adding new variable did the trick. thanks again

Comment: Ok. Happy to help.

Comment: Yah I just changed the var pt position. anyways it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have overcomplicated your `productpagetotal()` function a bit. The issue is that you are using the previously calculated value in your `.product-total-price` `span` as the quantity multiplier for subsequent calculations (that is why you are getting that exponential growth effect regardless of whether you increment or decrement). You need to store you base price somewhere and use that for your calculation (rather than trying to incorporate your most recent total into the calculation).

Following is an example using an additional `data-price` attribute in your `.product-total-price` element to store the base price along with a simplified `productpagetotal()` function (but there are lots of other ways you could handle storing the base price):

```js
var increment = document.querySelector('#myform .qtyplus');
var decrement = document.querySelector('#myform .qtyminus');
increment.addEventListener('click', incrementValue);
decrement.addEventListener('click', decrementValue);

function incrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-number').value);
  if (isNaN(value) || value < 1) {
    value = 1;
  }
  
  value++;
  document.getElementById('input-number').value = value;
  productpagetotal();
}


function decrementValue() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input-number').value);
  if (isNaN(value) || value < 1) {
    value = 1;
  }
  
  value--;
  document.getElementById('input-number').value = value;
  productpagetotal();
}


function productpagetotal() {
  var totalPrice = document.querySelector('.product-total-price');
  var price = totalPrice.dataset.price;
  var quantity = document.getElementById('input-number').value;
  var sum = price * quantity;
  sum = Math.round(sum * 100) / 100;
  totalPrice.innerHTML = '$' + sum;
}
```

```html
<div class="quant">
  <p>Qty</p>
  <form id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' id="input-number" name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="last-list">
  <h6 style="font-size: 17px">Free Shipping on Order over $80</h6>
  <h4 class="in-h4">Delivery to pincode 000001 - within 2-4 business days</h4>
  <div class="total-price">
    <span>Total Price</span>
    <span class="span product-total-price" data-price="24.99">$24.99</span>
    <button class="add-to-card">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>
```